# Join Attributes by Location: .mdb and shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, spatial-join, personal-geodatabase

I can join attributes by location in QGIS using 2 shapefiles.

However, I do not know how to do the join when one of my files is in a .mdb format while the other is a shapefile.

Comment: This might help: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26749/how-to-export-mdb-file-to-shapefile

Comment: I have checked this link, and as I understand, I have to download a trial copy of ArcGIS then use Catalog to convert it. However I need more details on how to use Catalog to transfer a .mdb file to a .shp file. Please advise.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is beyond my scope as I am only familiar with QGIS. Hopfully others will advise.

Comment: Do you know how to transfer a .mdb file to a .shp file in QGIS? Thanks.

Comment: I, as well, have not used ArcGIS before. I only know how to use QGIS.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! In general, a good question should show some research effort and explain what you have tried already and what exactly did not work.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used .mdb files (not yet anyway!) so I am not sure if the following will work but I believe this is how you can import .mdb files:

*Layer* > *Add Vector Layer...* > select *Database* > *ESRI Personal GeoDatabase*

[image: Add vector layer toolbar]

[image: Add vector layer interface]

Perhaps then you can do a join...?